# Dynamic Formula with VBA: Reference Another Sheet with Index/Match

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to find the date that an ID# was entered. I have a pivot table that shows the ID# as a page filter, and I am trying to use a formula to find the ID# in a separate worksheet and return the date. 
Here is the problem: I have already successfully written a VBA code to find the date, and it works, however-- when the page filter is changed and another ID# is selected, the date doesn't update.

So I want to have VBA insert a formula so the reference is dynamic. I've spent 3 workdays on this and cannot get it to work...

The ID# is in wsh.C1
rc_rt is the number of rows in the data worksheet wsrt

```
    wsh.Range("D1").Formula = "=" & WorksheetFunction.Index(wsrt.Range("D2:N" & rc_rt), _
        WorksheetFunction.Match(wsh.Range("C1"), wsrt.Range("D2:D" & rc_rt), 0), 11)
    wsh.Range("D1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

This works! But if I change the ID# in C1, D1 doesn't change (I want it to)
Time_By_CO = wsh
Recorded_Time = wsrt

```
    wsh.Range("E1") = "= 'Time_By_CO'!C1" 'Returns correct value
    wsh.Range("F1") = "=MATCH('Time_By_CO'!$C$1, 'Recorded_Time'!$D$2:$N$" & rc_rt & ", 0)"
            'Returns #N/A
    wsh.Range("D2").Formula = "=INDEX('Recorded_Time'!D2:N" & rc_rt & ", MATCH('Time_By_CO'!C1, Recorded_Time!D2:N" & rc_rt & ", 0), 11)"
            'Returns #N/A
```

This doesn't work. I thought it was an issue with the last argument in INDEX (offset by 11) but the MATCH function doesn't work either.

Other considerations: I've tried both fixed/unfixed ranges using $A$1 format and it makes no difference. 
I also have considered using a worksheet code to find it every time the pivot table is updated, but this is an issue because after the Macro is run a number of times, there is a problem with This:

```
With PCh_bar 'Chart formatting.
'{
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered 'Sets PivotChart as a bar graph.
    With .SeriesCollection("Est Time") 'Returns error sometimes?
    '{
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 188, 255)
    .ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowValue
    '}
    End With
```

It's only solved by deleting the sheet, and therefore would delete the worksheet code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what do you use to trigger the code? worksheet_change event?

Comment: It is in a much bigger sub that is called from another module.

Comment: In your MATCH formulas you only need to supply a single column (D) to search in, not D:N as you have in your posted code.